# Angular8 ReactiveForms: radio button input with same name in different FormGroup's?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a formGroup that will have dynamically added and removed nested formGroups. Each of nested formGroups should have formControl which is displayed as radio-button input.

For example, it could be a dynamic list of tasks and only one of those tasks could be marked as top-priority.

Simplified code example could look like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form = new FormGroup({});
    group1 =  new FormGroup({});
    control1 = new FormControl();

    group2 =  new FormGroup({});
    control2 = new FormControl();

    value: any = {};
    changed = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.form.addControl('group1', this.group1);
      this.form.addControl('group2', this.group2);

      this.group1.addControl('radioInput', this.control1);
      this.group2.addControl('radioInput', this.control2);

      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe( (value) => {this.value = value; this.changed++;});
  }
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="id1" value="value1" [attr.name]="radioInput" [formControl]="control1">
      control1
  </div>

  <div>
      <input type="radio" id="id2" value="value2" [attr.name]="radioInput" [formControl]="control2">
       control2
   </div>

</form>

formValue: {{ value | json }}
<br>
formChangeCount: {{ changed }}
```

In this case, HTML template works perfectly and allows only one radio-button to be active at a time. But in the component top level formGroup is incorrectly 'adding' each checked radio-button to its value without removing previously checked radio-button.

How can i make formGroup to act in the same way as corresponding HTML does?

Stackblitz code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8atmn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Change ts file to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: "my-app",
 templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
 })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

radioForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}


 createForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
     radioInput: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
print(){
 console.log(this.radioForm.value);
 }


 ngOnInit() {
   this.radioForm = this.createForm();
 }
}
```

And your HTML to:

```
<form [formGroup]="radioForm">

 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="id1" value="value1" formControlName="radioInput">
  control1
 </div>

 <div>
  <input type="radio" id="id2" value="value2" formControlName="radioInput">
   control2
 </div>

</form>
<button class="btn" (click)="print()">Console Log Form</button>
```

Now every time you pick a radiobutton the value of radioInput change!You can see it on console every time you press your button

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this a bit different from what i am looking for. You have only one static formGroup and one formControl that both radio inputs reference to. When in my case, i need to have dynamic formGroup with multiple nested formGroup's that each have its own radio button.

Comment: Yes and that's what i am doing in reality, but just for this example i removed that part out of scope to simplify it. Issue is with radio buttons and not with formArray.